# Json decode string not working on php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

It was working perfectly on one day i see it is the below json decode not working.

```
<?php

$data = $_POST["data"];

$jsonString= urldecode(stripslashes($data));

$input = json_decode($jsonString, true);

$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");

fwrite($fh, $input);


fclose($fh)
```

I have checked the value of $data and $jsonString it is having a vaild json string. 
But the string $input is empty.any suggestion...?

Comment: If your json string is valid, then you get an associative array back, but `fwrite()` only takes a string. So you should get an error message if you have error reporting turned on: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>`

Comment: seems `$jsonString` does not contains valid json

Comment: have u checked with json_last_error_msg?

Answer (score 0):

please check with and get the error number and post it

```
echo json_encode($jsonString, true);
echo json_last_error_msg();

function json_last_error_msg() {
static $errors = array(
    JSON_ERROR_NONE             => null,
    JSON_ERROR_DEPTH            => 'Maximum stack depth exceeded',
    JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH   => 'Underflow or the modes mismatch',
    JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR        => 'Unexpected control character found',
    JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX           => 'Syntax error, malformed JSON',
    JSON_ERROR_UTF8             => 'Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded'
);
$error = json_last_error();
return array_key_exists($error, $errors) ? $errors[$error] : "Unknown error ({$error})";
```

}